# PHP: HTML Tags Not Rendering

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Hope y'all can help!

I'm using a PHP driven link directory program and, fo some reason, the summary descriptions recorded to my MySQL database and being generated, BUT the HTML tags won't render on the page. I've included the code below and here's an http://abiautism.com/autism-resources/?page=pages&id=2 Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<?php if ($rowpages[IMAGENAME]  != "") { ?>
<?php if ($rowpages[WIDTH] == '') $rowpages[WIDTH] = '128px'; ?>
<?PHP
$filename = "$svr_rootscript/product_images/$rowpages[IMAGENAME].jpg";
    if (file_exists($filename)) $ext = jpg;

 $filename = "$svr_rootscript/product_images/$rowpages[IMAGENAME].png";
    if (file_exists($filename)) $ext = png;
?>
<?PHP if ($ext != '') { ?>
<img class="photo" src="product_images/<?php echo $rowpages[IMAGENAME]; ?>.<?php echo $ext; ?>"     width="<?php echo $rowpages[WIDTH]; ?>"> 
<?PHP } ?>
<?PHP } ?>
<h1><?php echo $rowpages[HEADER]; ?></h1>

<h3><?php $description = preg_replace("/\n/","\n<BR>",$rowpages[CAPTION]); ECHO $description;   ?></h3>

<?PHP if ($rowpages[SHOWADS] != '') { ?>
<div align ="center"><?php echo $rowxxx[ADS]; ?></div>
<?PHP } ?>

<b><p><a href="<?php echo $rowpages[URL]; ?>" target="_blank"><? echo $pages_vst; ?></a></p></b>

<?php $description = preg_replace("/\n/","\n<BR>",$rowpages[PAGECONTENT]); ECHO    $rowpages[PAGECONTENT]; ?>
```

Comment: @CrayonViolent Agreed. Stop the madness also be consistent in using `<?php` (lowercase)  I literally didn't even bother to look at the code in that it is so ugly I don't want to dig through it.

Comment: @CrayonViolent Computers are generally more patient than waiters. ;-)

Comment: @CrayonViolent Geezus. Throw me under a bus for not knowing PHP. I thought that's what these foums were for. I was just looking for a little help from experts like yourself. BTW, I didn't write the code; I'm just looking to tweek it so it works. And, in keeping with your analogy, this is like a waiter asking for your order and then telling you to FKOFF.

Comment: @MojoMan if I was a waiter and someone did that to me, I prolly would tell them to FKOFF. I don't subscribe to the "customer is always right" paradigm - you pay to place an order and get some food, not treat the waiter like a slave or otherwise be a douche about things. Not that I am saying you were being disrespectful.  And neither was I. I was merely pointing out that the code is ugly.  I'm not sure why you would take it personal since you didn't even write the code, but even if you did, how do you expect to get better if you can't deal with someone pointing out the flaws? chillax man.

Comment: @MojoMan and also, in my analogy, php is the waiter, not me (well, the SO community), and your code is your code, not you. And not even your code, according to you.  Again, chillax man.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
echo htmlspecialchars_decode($content_html);
```

This change the `&lt;` to <

Comment: Yes, but why are those too many encoded `&amp;lt;`s in there?

Comment: I don't know maybe you change this chars when you save on the database